# Uncaught TypeError: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator)) at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous>

Tags: javascript, json, api

```
const container = document.querySelector("#container");

request.open("GET","https://datausa.io/api/data?drilldowns=Nation&measures=Population") ; 


request.send();

// to get the response


request.addEventListener("load",function(){

    //  console.log( this.responseText);

     const [data]= JSON.parse(this.responseText);
     console.log(data);

    //  const htmlData ="<div></div>";
    // container.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin",htmlData)
})
```

I am getting error in JSON.parse(this.responseText) the above mentioned error is for this line,please help me solve it

Comment: Have you tried looking at the response before doing `JSON.parse`? Have you tried looking at the parsed response before doing `const [ data ] =`…?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need [] or {} surrounding **data**. Just **data** is enough in this case.

```
const data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
```

Answer (score -1):

The call returns this:

```json
{"data":[{"ID Nation":"01000US","Nation":"United States","ID Year":2019,"Year":"2019","Population":328239523,"Slug Nation":"united-states"},{"ID Nation":"01000US","Nation":"United States","ID Year":2018,"Year":"2018","Population":327167439,"Slug Nation":"united-states"},{"ID Nation":"01000US","Nation":"United States","ID Year":2017,"Year":"2017","Population":325719178,"Slug Nation":"united-states"},{"ID Nation":"01000US","Nation":"United States","ID Year":2016,"Year":"2016","Population":323127515,"Slug Nation":"united-states"},{"ID Nation":"01000US","Nation":"United States","ID Year":2015,"Year":"2015","Population":321418821,"Slug Nation":"united-states"},{"ID Nation":"01000US","Nation":"United States","ID Year":2014,"Year":"2014","Population":318857056,"Slug Nation":"united-states"},{"ID Nation":"01000US","Nation":"United States","ID Year":2013,"Year":"2013","Population":316128839,"Slug Nation":"united-states"}],"source":[{"measures":["Population"],"annotations":{"source_name":"Census Bureau","source_description":"The American Community Survey (ACS) is conducted by the US Census and sent to a portion of the population every year.","dataset_name":"ACS 1-year Estimate","dataset_link":"http://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs/","table_id":"B01003","topic":"Diversity","subtopic":"Demographics"},"name":"acs_yg_total_population_1","substitutions":[]}]}
```

And as you can see this is an object not an array, so to get data key from the object you need to use curly brackets instead of normal brackets.

Like this:

```js
const {data} = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
```